# Catching exceptions in service layer without hiding bugs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exceptions

Let's imagine we have a service `CustomerService`:

```
public class CustomerService
{
    public Customer GetCustomer(string customerName)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(customerName));

        try
        {
            var customer = customerRepository.GetByName(customerName);
            return customer;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

This service is used in a controller `MyController`:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
     /* Properties */

     public ActionResult CustomerStuff(string customerName)
     {
          try
          {
              var customer = _customerService.GetCustomer(customerName);
              return View(customer);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              // Redirect to error page, etc...
          }
     }
}
```

The problem with this is that I hide possible `ArgumentNullException` which is probably caused by a bug in my code. I never expect anything to pass `null` to `GetCustomer`, but `catch(Exception)` in `MyController` hides this exception with the rest of exceptions. On the other hand, on production I want to redirect users if something goes wrong in the `CustomerService`, because e.g. connection timeout occured.

How can this problem be resolved without tons of code, such as:

```
try
{

}
catch (Exception ex) when (!(ex is ArgumentNullException))
{
    // handle timeouts, network availability, etc..
}
```

One possible solution I can see is creating a custom exception, such as `ServiceException` and throwing it inside `try/catch` in `GetCustomer` method. Is there any other technique that is maybe more common?

Comment: Can you create a "developer mode," where the error page shows the full exception details that caused the page to be shown? When releasing into production, the "developer mode" feature would be disabled to avoid bothering the end-users with such details.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I think this is the way to go. Thank you, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau jup asp.net core supports this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your service to:

```
public class CustomerService
{
    public Customer GetCustomer(string customerName)
    {
        try
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(customerName));

            var customer = customerRepository.GetByName(customerName);
            return customer;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

That way, your logger catches the argument error, along with all other errors. The controller then needs no special logic to handle specific exceptions.

Comment: The point is I don't want to catch `ArgumentNullException`. This exception is probably caused by a bug in the code and I don't want to hide it in `catch`. I want it to crash application.

Comment: @FCin, You aren't catching it as your catch block contains a `throw`. So it gets logged but still then gets sent to the controller for it to "crash your app", ie show a 500 internal error page.

Comment: So your solution involves removing `try/catch` in `MyController` and handling exceptions by configuring error pages?

Comment: @FCin, no my solution is as per my answer with nothing else changing, as your controller already catches all exceptions and redirects to an error page.

Comment: But this code will catch `ArgumentNullException` in `MyController` and I don't want that. I want `ArgumentNullException` to crash my application and all other exceptions to be logged and redirected to error page. Of course I want this to be true for `ArgumentNullException` and `ArgumentException` and `InvalidOperationException`, etc. because these exceptions serve different purpose. These should never be thrown in properly working application, so I don't want to log them, but fix them whenever I see them. They indicate bugs.

Comment: @FCin: If you know at the point where you throw an exception that you can only get there if there is a bug in the application, you could also use `Debug.Assert` or `Trace.Assert` instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: @FCin, so you literally want them to crash the app, rather than showing an error page? Seems extreme, but you can handle this for example by calling `Thread.Abort(ex)` in the logger if it's one of those exceptions. That method throws a `ThreadAbortException`. which can be caught, but is automatically re-thrown at the end of the catch block. It cannot therefore be stopped from propagating all the way up through your app.This will therefore log the error in the live system as well as killing the app dead.

Comment: @DavidArno I want to crash app, because this will happen only for developers. End users should never experience this, because all possible occurences of this exception should be fixed in development. Throwing `ArgumentNullException` means someone introduced bug somewhere else, because there is no business justification for null/empty `customerName`. One reason might be, someone forgot to write validation for this variable (like I did in `CustomerStuff` method).

Comment: @FCin, "*I want to crash app, because this will happen only for developers*". No, that is effectively impossible. Unless you never release your app, at some stage you'll have to ship it and it *will* contain bugs, not matter how many weeks, months, years etc you've spent testing. So end users will experience this.

Comment: @DavidArno Of course, I'm talking about "perfect world". There are going to be bugs in real world, but I was thinking about crashing app in development and redirecting to error pages in production. So `ArgumentNullException` exceptions would be caught by asp.net framework in production and thrown in development. Maybe I'm not explaining this very well. I think solution provided by @Bart van Ingen Schenau is what I need to do. There is global exception handling system that redirects to error page on production and displays different amount of information depending on whether it is debug or prod